# An example of random functions that are stochastically equivalent but aren't modifications of each other.

Tags: examples-counterexamples, equivalence-relations, random-functions

I'm trying to show that stochastic equivalence of  random functions (in the broad sense) doesn't imply that they are modifications of each other. For this, I'm looking for a counterexample. Perhaps you've seen something like this. I would be grateful for any information.

Comment: Could you remind us what "stochastic equivalence " means here, please?

Comment: @kimchi X={$X_t, t\in T$} and Y={$Y_t, t\in T$} are stochastically equivalent if on $\otimes\varepsilon_t$(product  sigma algebra), $t\in T:  $ $P_X=P_Y$(distributions).

Comment: Let $X(t)$ be a standard Brownian motion.  Then isn't $Y(t)= -X(t)$  stochastically equivalent in this sense to $X(t)$ but not a modification?

Comment: @kimchi Thanks for your answer ! It really helped.